# Mac OSX Lion: Switch on SMB share depending on network connection

Tags: mac-osx, server-message-block, osx-lion

we have a Scanner that can save the scanned documents to an SMB share.
So I need to switch on SMB sharing on the Mac - should be no problem.

Issue: The Mac is a MacBook, which will also be used in foreign networks - and obviously we would not want SMB sharing on outside my own network.

So, I am looking for a way to automatically start the SMB service on the MacBook only if it gets connected to a certain netowrk (ideally based on HW adress of our router, or maybe based on the IP adress is gets from the DHCP server as a fallback). The SMB serive should be stopped as soons as the network connection changes.

I am not sure if it is a good idea to fiddle with the system scripts, which might get changed by any next system update - still that might be the only option?
Or is there an app that can do that?
Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Hmm...  I think it's somewhat off-topic here, but it's been answered on SuperUser, and the answer might be useful to some wayward Mac admin in the future.  I won't kill it in case someone comes up with something better/not-costly :)

Comment: @voretaq7: Agreed :) I already learned something new from this, never heard about this NetworkLocation/Sidekick tool from your answer and it looks useful.

Comment: @SvenW All credit goes to alexandru on SuperUser who deserves upvotes on for their answer on the linked question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liberally stolen from https://superuser.com/questions/187650/enable-file-sharing-only-when-on-home-wi-fi-network-in-mac-os-x :

---

Even if slightly expensive, you can use [NetworkLocation](http://centrix.ca/NetworkLocation/) to autodetect your location, and after configuring it for your home network, add `Application` > `Open an Application / Run Script` and configure it so that it runs this [StartInternetSharing](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/79900/tools/StartInternetSharing.scpt) script. Repeat, only this time check the box saying `Launch when leaving location` and add the [StopInternetSharing](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/79900/tools/StopInternetSharing.scpt) script instead.

Scripts weren't written by me, but I've updated them and hosted them on my Dropbox because I have a checkbox for Xgrid, and so the original version wasn't working. I've tested them and they both work. Here is the [MacRumors post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=5463302&postcount=5) where these scripts were originally posted.

P.S. I don't know if I have Xgrid because of something I installed, or everyone with 10.6 does. Could you read/follow the instructions in either script's headers (open in AppleScript Editor) and let me know if you do? I'd like to update the scripts to have the most-used option as default. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks perfect - I will go for it!  And sorry for being off-topic.  For any others interested: The referenced product is now called [Sidekick](http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/).  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You do *not* need to enable SMB sharing to use the scanner. The scanner should be configured to save scanned documents to a *server* on the network in question. You then make an *outbound* SMB connection to that server in order to retrieve those files. If the privacy of scanned documents is a concern, ensure that each user has a scan folder that is accessible only by the user and by the scanner's service account (which should be named `svc_scanner`, or whatever follows your company's service naming convention).

If you really want to enable SMB sharing for one authorized device to connect to your Mac, you can use `ipfw` to ensure that connections are allowed *only* from that specific device's IP address. If you do not want to configure `ipfw` manually, [WaterRoof](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/) is one option for a GUI front-end.

Comment: +1 for not enabling the sharing *on your Mac* -- you should be able to access SMB shares without sharing anything yourself (though you may have to open the firewall up to get it working)

Comment: Sorry I fogot to mention that there is no server. Otherwise, that would obviously be the best option.

Comment: I thought about the firewall, but Lion only allows me to select programs and choose to allow or deny incoming traffic - I cannot find any "from" adress option or what I would expect in a firewall...

Comment: @Philippp My mistake: forgot that the firewall settings under System Preferences are now application-only. Revised accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

We just found an even more promising solution:
See http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/
On gitHub: [ControlPlane on GitHub](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/)
So its even open source!